# Given a 2D list (matrix), how to find the largest element and print its row and column number?

Tags: python

I need to find the row and column number for the largest element of an MxN 2D list. If there is more than on, I want to report the one with the smallest row and column number. If possible, I want to do it without numpy as I am still trying to get the hang of Python by doing these exercises.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
# m rows and n integers (columns)
m = 3
n = 4
# The 2D-list
arr = [[0, 3, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 5, 5],
       [5, 1, 2, 3]]
```

And the output would then need to be:

```
[1, 2]
```

As the **first 5** is the largest element with the smallest row and column number.

I have gotten as far as finding the largest value per row, but now I just need to compare this per column and the print the indices. This is what I have up to now:

```
# m rows and n integers (columns)
m = 3
n = 4
MxN = [m, n]
# The 2D-list
arr = [[0, 3, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 5, 5],
       [5, 1, 2, 3]]

for i in range(MxN[0]):
    row = arr[i]
    maxValue = max(row)
    index = row.index(maxValue)
    print(maxValue, index)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
4 3
5 2
5 0
```

I have no idea how to go on further.

Comment: You need to use two for loops, keep track of the element that you found as max value and just store the row and column index into 2 variables. after the for loops, you would be having the max value, and the row,col where you found that max value in your 2D matrix. no need for using numpy for such simple case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over rows and columns save the index when find a larger number.

```py
# m rows and n integers (columns)
m = 3
n = 4
MxN = [m, n]
# The 2D-list
arr = [[0, 3, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 5, 5],
       [5, 1, 2, 3]]

max_num = float("-inf")
index = [-1, -1]

for i in range(MxN[0]):
    for j in range(MxN[1]):
        if arr[i][j] > max_num:
            max_num = arr[i][j]
            index = [i, j]

print(index)
```